# Hibernate Cascade and Foreign Key issues

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, cascade

I am learning hibernate cascade to implement it for our application. Application's SQL Server database design is based on some legacy db model with weak/improper FK relation. And I am having trouble mapping entities while using Hibernate Cascade to fetch data from related tables.

Consider the scenario:

```
TABLE_A:
ColA1 and ColA2 makes composite key

(int)   (int)   (string)
ColA1   ColA2   ColA3
1       1       dummy111
1       2       dummy222
2       1       dummy333
2       2       dummy444

Table_B
ColB1 and ColB2 makes composite key

(int)   (int)
ColB1   ColB2
1       1
1       2
2       1
2       2

Table_C
ColC1 and ColC2 makes composite key

(int)   (int)   (int)   (str)   (str)
ColC1   ColC2   ColC3   ColC4   ColC5
1       1       1       AA      dummy999
1       2       1       BB      dummy888
1       2       2       AA      dummy777

Colc1 and ColC3 makes foreign key with (ColA1 and ColA2 for Table_A when ColC4=AA) or (ColB1 and ColB2 for Table_B when ColC4=BB). 
This FK is not defined in table or schema but is just written on documents and is implemented across all stored procedures currently used in the application.  
So if you notice Table C, ColC1 and ColC3 can have same values (ex, 1,1) and are not unique values that properly make a FK relation. And ColC4 is not present in Table_A or Table_B.
```

Three entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class AEntity implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private AEntityPK id; //Composite key of ColA1 and ColA2 


//bi-directional many-to-one association to CEntity
@OneToMany(mappedBy="centity", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<WmktEmpSbadWd> centityList;

}


@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class BEntity implements Serializable {


@EmbeddedId
private BAEntityPK id; //Composite key of ColB1 and ColB2 


//bi-directional many-to-one association to CEntity
@OneToMany(mappedBy="centity", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<WmktEmpSbadWd> centityList;

}


@Entity
@Table(name="C")
public class CEntity implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private CAEntityPK id; //Composite key of ColC1 and ColC2 


//bi-directional many-to-one association to AEntity
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="ColA1", referencedColumnName="ColC1", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="ColA2", referencedColumnName="ColC3", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false),
    })
private AEntity aentityObj;



//bi-directional many-to-one association to BEntity
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="ColB1", referencedColumnName="ColC1", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="ColB2", referencedColumnName="ColC3", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false),
    })
private BEntity bentityObj;



}

Sample Test Class to fetch AEntoty and its related data from CEntity:

public class TestFetchEntityA{
public static void main(){
.....
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
aentityList = session.createQuery("FROM AEntity WHERE ColA1=1 and ColA2=1").list();

}

}
```

Executing main() fetches two objects for CEntity class in centityList from AEntity since I haven't defined the condition (ColC4="AA") in mapping that is defined in Table_C for FK.

So what to do if I have to add condition (ColC4="AA") while mapping AEntity and CEntity ?

Note: In real application there are 20-30 tables with massive amount of rows that are mapped with 5-6 tables based on the scenario mentioned above.

I tried following but don't work:

1. Join between AEntity and CEntity in createquery(), it fetches values from only these two tables. But I have multiple entities to be cascaded and those are ignored when I use join.
2. With @JoinFormula I see just the columns can be determined based on condition and not the mapping itself.